# Reusing style and setting feature text label in OpenLayers?

Tags: openlayers

In OpenLayers 5 I have a vector layer which can display 16K features in certain portions of the map. Each feature has a text label that displays a unique name.

If I create a new style for each feature so I can dynamically set the Text string I run into performance problems where the browser rendering crashes/hangs.

Alternatively, if I create a style cache and reuse the styles when the text label is set for one feature all the other feature text labels change.

Is there a way to reuse style object instances and have the text label be different for each feature?

Comment: Use a single style and a style function which calls `.getText().setText(...)` as in the examples https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/vector-layer.html